# Conversor de C# para JavaScript: ((objeto)sender).atributo

Tags: javascript, c#

Estou desenvolvendo um conversor de C# para JavaScript e estou em um entrave, quando o código tiver uma linha de código assim:

```
((CONTROLE)sender).Atributo 
Exemplo:((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl
```

Qual o código correspondente em JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript puro ou você usa um Framework para converter?

Comment: JavaScript puro.

Answer (score 3):

Veja, em C#, você está dizendo:

((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl

-Pegue o objeto "sender" e faça um Cast pro tipo 'ImageButton';
-Com o objeto resultante (que é uma instancia de 'ImageButton'), pegue a propriedade ImageUrl (que faz parte do tipo ImageButton);

Pois bem, javascript é uma linguagem fracamente tipada. Esse cast é desnecessário. Se o objeto for do tipo ImageButton, a propriedade ImageUrl estará lá, sem você precisar do cast. Bastará:

sender.ImageUrl.

Caso precise atestar o cast, use typeof para verificar a classe da instancia.